# jms multithreaded open connections issues

Tags: java, jms

I am creating a stand alone java multithreaded application (using LinkedBlockingQueue)which sends xml messages to a jms queue.This jar file is invoked as a jxsp (java extended stored procedure) from teradata box. Issue we are facing is that , messages are getting published to queue, but the jms connection opened is not getting closed.
Do i need to call threadpoolexecutors shutdown method?
Regards
Pradeep S

Comment: how about the bit of code with publishes the message to the queue?

Comment: Are you using a try finally block?

Comment: the issue was resolved after putting threadpoolexecutor.shutdown()